# Map over Navbar

Tags: html, css

how can I avoid that the map goes over the navbar. Navbar is fixed, I only want the map behind the navbar while scrolling down.

It would be so kind if anyone could help me out.
THX

```
/**
*map == GoogleMap.div
*/
#map{
position: inherit;
width:500px;
height:500px;
background: transparent; 
left: 50%; 
margin-left: -250px;
}

ul.topnav {
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
overflow: hidden;
background-color: #333;
position: fixed;
top: 0;
width: 100%;
}

ul.topnav li {float: left;}

ul.topnav li a {
font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida                      Grande''Lucida Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
display: block;
color: white;
text-align: center;
padding: 18px 20px;
text-decoration: none;
}

ul.topnav li a:hover:not(.active) {background-color: #111;}

ul.topnav li a.active {background-color: #D2691E;}
```

Comment: Hello, have you tried adding a z-index to your navbar ?

Comment: can you post your html too? 
Have you tried z-index?

Comment: @CorentinPRUNE && @Naomi ... poblem solved, used `z-index: -1;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to tell without seeing your HTML, but the map is likely showing up on top of the navbar simply because it is lower in the document flow, and the embedded map elements get absolute positioning. I do not a z-index on your navbar, so try giving it a z-index greater than 0.

Unless you assign a >0 z-index to the navbar, elements with BOTH of these two attributes will always be above it in the document flow:

- Relative, absolute, or fixed positioning
- Coded below your navbar in the HTML

A lot of people choose `z-index: 10;` for their navbar; it's easy to remember, and there's still plenty of space to play around with z-index below and above. But anything above zero will work.

Check out this codepen for an example, with some additional style comments on the code you pasted in: http://codepen.io/roraback/pen/RpYQeR